# Merge two lists of dictionaries ignoring None entries

Tags: python

I have the below two lists:

```
a = [{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}, {'a3': 3}]
b = [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}, None]
```

I would like to merge them creating an output like the below, ignoring the None elements.

```
desired_output = [{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}, {'a3': 3}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`.

```py
res = [(x or {}) | (y or {}) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: That is amazing. Could you please briefly explain what it does?

Comment: @JaviTorre `zip` groups corresponding elements from the two lists together. `x or {}` will use `x` if it is truthy (not None in this case) or use an empty dict otherwise. `x | y` merges two dicts together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function and a list comprehension to merge the two lists and ignore the None elements. Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
a = [{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}, {'a3': 3}, None, {'a4': 4}]
b = [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}, None, {'b3': 4, 'b4': 5}, {'b5': 4, 'b6': 5}]

desired_output = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(a, b) if None not in [d1,d2]]

print(desired_output)

# [{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}, {'a4': 4, 'b5': 4, 'b6': 5}]
```

In this example, the zip function combines the elements of the two lists `a` and `b` into pairs `(d1, d2)`. The list comprehension iterates over these pairs, and for each pair, it uses the `**` operator to merge the two dictionaries and only considering the case when neither of `d1` nor `d2` is `None`.